# Book where a girl's reflection tricks her into swapping places?

Tags: story-identification

I could have sworn the book was one of the Goosebumps series but I can't seem to find it. The book was about this girl who didn't like how she looked and one day she looked in the mirror and her reflection started talking to her. The reflection wanted to be her! So it tricked her into letting her out and putting herself into the reflection realm. Does anyone know what book this is?

Comment: Dunno about a book, but something very similar happens in the first season of Sabrina the Teenage Witch. ("Sabrina Through the Looking Glass")

Comment: Did the girl in the mirror hate dressing up, while the original girl loved it? I may have read this story when I was younger.

Answer (score 7):

It's *[Don't Look in the Mirror](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3190708-don-t-look-in-the-mirror)* by Larry Weinberg. Just found it myself.

[image: Book cover]

> Alice has always hated her appearance. So it's a very strange feeling when, looking in a mirror one day, she sees a more beautiful version of herself staring back! Even more surprising, the image begins speaking. Demanding to be called Alicia, the young woman in the mirror helps Alice get a sophisticated makeover--and a cute guy at school finally notices her.
>
> But what does Alicia want in return? It isn't very pretty, and Alice is soon fighting for her life.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! Please could you add some detail to this post, maybe a brief description of the work you're referring to, so that we can judge how well it matches the description in the question?

Comment: @Rand, looks like this is the OP. Perhaps they need to [merge accounts](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: @Mooz I took a peek at the account info, and it doesn't *seem* to be the OP. Probably a good idea to leave that link though just in case.

Answer (score 5):

It reminded me a bit of this one, which terrified me as a child: [Let's Get Invisible!](http://goosebumps.wikia.com/wiki/Let%27s_Get_Invisible)

The goosebumps wiki mentions another book with a similar premise: [Ghost in the Mirror](http://goosebumps.wikia.com/wiki/Ghost_in_the_Mirror).

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you'll see this but I came across this in searching for a very similar book--it wound up being "Mirror Mirror on the wall" by RL Stine. Just in case you were looking for the same book I figured I'd post.

Comment: "I don't know if you'll see this" - OP hasn't visited the site in six years, so probably not unfortunately. Welcome to SciFi.SE, though! For completeness' sake, you should explain how this matches the description in the question. (I'd note as well that RL Stine is the author of the Goosebumps books.)

Comment: Ditto to what F1Krazy said! You can [edit] further information into the answer. May I also interest you in taking the [tour]? :)

Answer (score 3):

Was Mirrormask a book? Because that sounds a bit like it... Check out Neil Gaimen. The movie is David Bowie wierd, but pretty good.