# Goosebumps episode about evil alter ego coming out of mirror

Tags: episode-identification, goosebumps

I remember quite a while back I watched a *Goosebumps* episode where some kids found a mirror that would bring their evil clone out in the attic or something like that, but I don’t know the name.

Comment: It wasn't an episode (it was a book) but it does fit the bill; http://goosebumps.wikia.com/wiki/Ghost_in_the_Mirror

Comment: possibly related to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24417/book-where-a-girls-reflection-tricks-her-into-swapping-places ?

Answer (score 6):

The episode is ["Let's Get Invisible!"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0591349/) (1996), based on the book.

> Max, his brother and his friend, Erin, discover a mirror which has the
> ability to turn them invisible. They have fun playing around with it
> at first, until the mirror starts to show a malevolent side.

[Alter ego:](https://www.tv.com/shows/goosebumps/lets-get-invisible-49631/recap/)

> That night when everybody was supposed to eat dinner, Noah became
> invisible. He ate and drank his dinner while he was invisible. His
> parents were looking everywhere for him. Max took him upstairs back to
> the attic and made him visible again. When he came back, Noah was
> strange. He talked different and he acted different.
>
> Later, Max came back from Baseball practice. But when he came home,
> Zack and Erin were upstairs in the attic playing with the mirror and
> becoming invisible. Zack was invisible and then he starts to feel
> dizzy and cold, and his voice was weird. When he was visible, he
> started acting strange like Noah. He made Max invisible. Then somehow,
> Max was pulled into the mirror in a weird dimension. He saw his
> reflection there talking to the Real Max. Erin saw that Zacks earring
> was on the wrong ear. Max's reflection kept talking about him taking
> Max's place and making the Real Max trapped in the mirror, but Max
> didnt want to. Erin pulls the cord and after a long period of time,
> Max came back...halfway frozen. He told Erin to break the mirror. When
> she did, everything went back to normal. But after the group left the
> room...the mirror fixed itself.
>
> When the Dad asked Noah to throw him something, Noah threw it with his right-hand. Did he and his reflection switch???

Full episode:

Comment: This one definitely seems correct. The only other possible one is "[*I am Your Evil Twin*](http://goosebumps.wikia.com/wiki/I_Am_Your_Evil_Twin)".