# Need to know the name of this 90s scifi paranormal show

Tags: story-identification, tv

I watched this show in 1991. One episode I remember is a teenage girl who had a crush on her teacher. She walked through a mirror and everything looked the same except it was backwards(?) She had a bad experience with the teacher and ended up having to come back. It was like an anthology series.

Comment: http://wizardsofwaverlyplace.wikia.com/wiki/All_About_You-Niverse

Comment: No,I'm sure it wasn't that, but thanks!

Comment: possibly related to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24417/book-where-a-girls-reflection-tricks-her-into-swapping-places ?

Answer (score 10):

I found it! It was a show called *[Beyond Reality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_Reality_(TV_series))* starring Shari Belafonte. The episode was called "[Mirror Mirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Beyond_Reality_episodes)".

> Anna, a student of J.J.’s, has learned how to enter another etheric plane – by crossing through her bedroom mirror into an alternate world where her romantic fantasies about J.J. are real. This other world turns dangerous when Anna is unable to find her way back. Laura hypnotizes J.J., allowing him to join Anna on the etheric plane and guide her back to reality.

### Episode

Comment: Can you please explain why you think this is the correct answer?

Comment: :) Other than being the person who asked the question?

Comment: That said, with better understanding of the site, I now realize that we were prompting her to provide details. I've posted what I could find.

Answer (score 7):

I can't find a specific matching episode (possibly only because the descriptions I can find are pretty vague), but I'm thinking that this may be [Are You Afraid Of The Dark?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Are_You_Afraid_of_the_Dark%3F). The original version aired from 1990 to 1996 and was a sci-fi/paranormal/scary story anthology show where the main cast would tell stories to their friends in "The Midnight Society". Excluding a few rare exceptions, each story/episode was completely separate from the other stories.

Comment: This was downvoted why? It may not be the answer the OP was looking for but it still shows research and a reason why @phantom42 thinks it might be the correct show. Seriously, why don't people ask to others to **edit** their post and give them time make changes or repost as a comment instead of immediately downvoting. Pretty discouraging to new users especially. +1

Comment: I checked out the link, but it(AYAOTD)didn't start airing in the US until August of 1992,so that would be too late.