# Teen fiction book about a girl who swapped places with her mirror self

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I read this story back in primary school. This girl was unsatisfied with her life, her mother, boyfriend and everyone else. One day she notices that her reflection seemed to be moving slower than her. I can't remember if it started talking to her immediately or if it was a slower transition, but they started talking about how much they hated their lives and how the others sounded so much better, so they switched lives.

Ultimately, the main character (MC) realized that she liked her life much better, but it was too late, because her mirror self didn't want to swap back. They fought, the mirror broke, and the MC's mother got stuck there too. NSFW warning: the mirror girl ended up sleeping with the MC's boyfriend. Can't remember how it ends... Also, the main girl ends up going to the psych ward (maybe framed by mirror girl?) I'm not sure.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this book, and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: Possibly [Don't Look in the Mirror by Larry Weinberg](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/122433/20774)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might this be ***[Eyes in the Mirror](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9683225-eyes-in-the-mirror)*** (2011) by Julia Mayer...?

From Goodreads:

> I always thought it would be cool to escape into another world. I never believed I'd find one in my reflection. But there I was, falling through the mirror into a parallel life-Samara's life. And she needed me. The cutting, the dead mom, no friends...She was hurting, and I knew it was up to me to fix it. She needed me to fix her.
>
> She'll thank me...
>
> Samara I never had a friend until I met Dee, at least not a real friend. But then she's my reflection, so maybe I'm just crazy. When she suggested we switch places, it seemed like the perfect answer.
> So I let her live in my world, and I lived in hers.
> With her mom, her boyfriend, her friends-her perfect life...I don't belong here.
>
> But how can I go back after what she's done?
>
> Two girls, one reflection, and a startling discovery about what really lies beyond the bathroom mirror...

From [Kirkus Reviews](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/julia-mayer/eyes-mirror/):

> Stoned, Dee’s attractive male friend Jamie suggests the existence of an alternate universe, and later the 16-year-old finds it by stepping through a mirror.
>
> On the other side, she encounters Samara, her alter ego. Where Dee is a good student and rarely steps off the straight and narrow, Samara, an unhappy loner since her mother committed suicide three years before, savors cutting herself, an act that’s vividly depicted a few times throughout the narrative. Told in these two girls’ voices in alternate chapters, their stories interweave when they inexplicably decide to swap places for a day or two. Samara encourages Jamie’s sexual advances, and Dee tells Samara’s father about her cutting, leaving both teens with new issues when they return to their own worlds. While Samara must deal with therapy, Dee faces greater trials. Though these push her off her college-track, she adjusts with remarkably minor angst. The quality of writing is uneven, too often telling rather than showing and never managing to generate sufficient suspense to move the tale forward. Both Dee and Samara are described in detail, yet remain stock characters—good teen and troubled teen. Others are more superficially developed. While the concept is intriguing, the paranormal aspect is overshadowed by the less compelling reality-fiction component.
>
> Ultimately, this average debut effort never rises above the masses in either overcrowded genre.